# Face an issue about HttpStatusCode when I upgrade spring 3.1

Tags: kotlin, spring-mvc, junit

guys
I face a strange issue when I upgrade the sping 2.65 to 3.1.0.
This is the code:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.OK
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatusCode
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange


    @Test
    fun `and the operation is successful it should create and emit the audit event`() {
        private val mockExchange = mockk<ServerWebExchange>()
        every { mockExchange.authorizationData() } returns null
        every { mockExchange.response.statusCode } returns HttpStatus.OK

        mockSuccessfulFilterOperations()

        assertDoesNotThrow {
            auditLoggerFilter.filter(mockExchange, mockChain).block()
        }

        verify(exactly = 1) { auditLoggerService.publishAuditEvent(any(), SUCCESS) }
        confirmVerified(auditLoggerService)
    }
```

Exception on (every { mockExchange.response.statusCode } returns HttpStatus.OK):

```
org.springframework.http.HttpStatusCode
java.lang.InstantiationError: org.springframework.http.HttpStatusCode
```

But I read the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.html), the  HttpStatus is not deprecated, why it has the exception?

I try to use:

```
every { mockExchange.response.statusCode } returns HttpStatusCode.valueOf(200)
```

It still cannot work.